# Overview customers that bought product x

Tags: magento, export, product

I've been checking the Magento Reports section already, but I cannot seem to find a report that helps me with the following:

I need to have an export that shows me all customers that bought product X. But how to generate it?

Comment: I don't believe there is a report for this built into Magento by default.